# Ctrl+S in fish shell does not work as in bash

Tags: fish

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> can be used to pause/resume output in bash shell.
But in fish shell, it does not work.
Are there any replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intentional. Fish disables terminal flow control because the original developers concluded the feature causes too many problems for inexperienced CLI users especially those used to emacs where [ctrl-s] is normally bound to the incremental search function and thus might type it at a shell prompt.

Answer (score -2):

On the upside, the same functionality can be added to your fish shell with a function and a key-binding.

See the following plugins, for example:

- https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-sudope
- https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-bang-bang (implements the `!!` variant)